# how to read all files inside particular folder

Tags: c#, xml, file

I want to read all xml files inside a particular folder in c# .net

```
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load((PG.SMNR.XMLDataSourceUtil.GetXMLFilePath(Locale, "Products/category/product.xml")));
```

i have multiple products in category folder.. want loop the folder and should get all product xml file names.

```
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load((PG.SMNR.XMLDataSourceUtil.GetXMLFilePath(Locale, "Products/category/x1.xml")));
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Where are you having difficulties? http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 304, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
...
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.xml"))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

Note the above uses a .NET 4.0 feature; in previous versions replace `EnumerateFiles` with `GetFiles`). Also, replace `File.ReadAllText` with your preferred way of reading xml files - perhaps `XDocument`, `XmlDocument` or an `XmlReader`.

Comment: 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateFiles'

Comment: "using System.IO;" Brilliant!!   Why can more people not give this? It can be so annoying to attempt to find what people are talking about

Comment: @user001 because usually the IDE can find and add such things for you - just press ctrl+.

Comment: @MarcGravell haha usually :(

Comment: I think it is better to use StringBuilder inside the loop to append every file's content.      sb.Append(File.ReadAllText(file));

Comment: @Vitrum nowhere did it say anything about appending them. Whatever the code does with the contents of each file: fine. But it doesn't mention appending *anywhere*. If you are appending, `ReadAllText` is also overhead - should loop inside the file, chunking.

Comment: Please put some example for folder path demo  @Marc Gravell

Answer (score 36):

```
using System.IO;

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.xml");
```

Answer (score 16):

```
using System.IO;

//...

  string[] files;

  if (Directory.Exists(Path)) {
    files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, @"*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    //...
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx) method:

```
FileInfo[] files = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.xml");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to copy all the text files in one folder to merge and copy to           another folder, you can do this to achieve that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace HowToCopyTextFiles
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string mydocpath=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);     
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string txtName in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Links","*.txt"))
      {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtName))
        {
          sb.AppendLine(txtName.ToString());
          sb.AppendLine("= = = = = =");
          sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
          sb.AppendLine();
          sb.AppendLine();   
        }
      }
      using (StreamWriter outfile=new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\AllTxtFiles.txt"))
      {    
        outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this It is working for me..

The syntax is `Directory.GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern);`

```
var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@filePath, "*.*");
```

This code will return all the files inside `App_Data` folder.

> The second parameter *.* indicates the searchPattern with File Extension where the first *
> is for file name and second is for format of the file or File Extension like (*.png -
> any file name with .png format.

Answer (score 2):

```
    using System.IO;
    string[] arr=Directory.GetFiles("folderpath","*.Fileextension");
      foreach(string file in arr)
       {

       }
```

Comment: Whilst this solution may answer the OP's problem, it is advised not to just write a code-only answer as this may not be very helpful to future users. Elaborate a little. What does this solution provide? How is it going to benefit the OP? etc.

Comment: i just seen yesterday code but that that is not a copy paste

Comment: I wasn't implying that you'd copy/pasted. I've updated my comment. Still, my comment still stands. Elaborate.