# How can I make my C# code check each file in a directory?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to read all files inside particular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840443/how-to-read-all-files-inside-particular-folder)

I have the following code which I came up with:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Notes\Variables1.txt");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
   process(line);
}

string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Notes\test1.txt");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
   process(line);
}
```

Is there a simple and reliable way that I can modify the code so that it looks up all the .txt files in my Notes directory and then reads each one in turn. Some way I can code this up without having to specify each file in turn and something that won't crash if the file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a collection of the files in any given directory using [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx). Then just process them one by one like you were already doing.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Notes", "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach(string file in files)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        process(line);
    }        
}
```

There's a lot more in the [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Thanks. By the way is there some way I can get the filename and put it into a string?

Comment: @Jason: It's already in the `string file`. If you need to strip away the extension, path, etc. you should fill this string into a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) or use the static methods of the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods.aspx) class.

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.txt");
foreach(string filename in files) 
{
   //go do something with the file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class to get a listing of all files.

Is has an overloaded [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413344.aspx) method, just for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
foreach(string filename in files)
{
   if (Path.GetExtension(filename) != ".txt")
      continue;

   string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename);
   foreach (string line in lines)
   {
      process(line);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.IO.Directory.ReadFiles`

For example:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Notes\", "*.txt")
```

Then simply iterate through the file paths

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
```

This will return an array of names so you can loop over each file in turn:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt"))
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        process(line);
    }
}
```