# Read all text files in a folder with StreamReader

Tags: c#

I am trying to read all *.txt* files in a folder using stream reader. I have this now and it works fine for one file but I need to read all files in the folder. This is what I have so far. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\ftp\inbox\test.txt")))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to read all files inside particular folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840443/how-to-read-all-files-inside-particular-folder)

Comment: -1 - I fail to see how this includes any research effort.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) method instead of.

> Returns an enumerable collection of file names that match a search
>   pattern in a specified path.

```
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt");
foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the files of a directory:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
```

Therefore you can iterate each file performing whatever you want. Ex: reading all lines.

And also you can use a file mask as a second argument for the `GetFiles` method.

Edit:

Inside this post you can see the difference between `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles`.

[What is the difference between Directory.EnumerateFiles vs Directory.GetFiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669617/directory-enumeratefiles-vs-getfiles)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` to find all files in a folder.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I am new to programming and I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Yes I do need to learn C#. That is why I'm in here. Can I use Directory.EnumerateFiles() along with stream reader?

Comment: @robertwoods: Yes.  You need to loop over the returned collection so that you can read each file.