# how to read all files in particular folder and filter more than one type?

Tags: c#

To loop through all files of one type, I do this :

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.txt"))
{
    (code here)
}
```

Taken from [how to read all files inside particular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840443/how-to-read-all-files-inside-particular-folder)

Is there a way to have 2 tags other than making two loops? Like having all *.bmp, *.png...

**NOTE : ANSWER I ACCEPTED DOWN HERE IS WAY MORE SIMPLE THAN THE ONE IN THE PROPOSED ANSWER, BUT BOTH WORKS.**

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate two results like this

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.txt").Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.bmp")))
{
    // (code here)
}
```

Or make it a function like so

```
    IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string folderPath, params string[] patterns)
    {
        return patterns.SelectMany(pattern => Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, pattern));
    }

    void Later()
    {
        foreach (var file in EnumerateFiles(".", "*.config", "*.exe"))
        {
         // (code here)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I find it more simple than the answer in the duplicate of my question!