# Copying files using C# and dos command

Tags: c#, dos

I want to include batch file into a main file.

```
//contents of copy.bat

copy *.txt Output.txt
```

Is there any direct solution using c#.  Following code generates no error at the 
cost of no output.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\mydir\copy.bat");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note : simply renaming some .txt file to .xls will not make it valid Excel file

Comment: How can someone who's been here for 4 years and with decent rep say "I don't know anything about C# so can you write all the code for me?". Aaaand... it's been edited out.

Comment: "*Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.*"

Comment: Your example does not follow my guideline. You don't have to invoke a *.bat file from C#. Just use C#'s build in APIs. I recommend you doing a basic C# course first ;-)

Answer (score 2):

### C#

- First you can read all files into a string:
  [how to read all files inside particular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840443/how-to-read-all-files-inside-particular-folder)

  - Then use StringBuilder to add the header to the file's content
  - Use File.WriteAllText to save it to the file sysem as currentdate.xls

Since you a learning, I won't give you a complete sample. It would just kill the learning effect. Problem with the approach is, that you load all contents in memory, which is limited. Just take a look at Streams, if you want to handle the task more efficiently (could be your exercise 2).

### .bat

Batch files are really not suitable for such a task. Take a look at PowerShell, if you want to do this as administrative task.

### Remark

Get an https://www.pluralsight.com/ account, they have excellent C# courses.