# How to open .rtf files as text stream

Tags: c#, .net, rtf, cs-script

I am very very novice to c# and .net and trying to understand it.

I am using solution from [how to read all files inside particular folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840443/how-to-read-all-files-inside-particular-folder) and trying to apply in my below code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace HowToCopyTextFiles
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string txtName in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Environ ment\Desktop\newfolder","*.rtf"))
      {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtName))
        {
          sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
          sb.AppendLine();
        }
      }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
  }
}
```

The result is ok but at the end of my test file it shows environment name.

like.

```
this is content of first file
this is content of second file
↑My environment full name                                            ↑My
environment full name        ↑My environment full name (Yes 3 times)
```

I am using cs-script, Is it due to that?

While using .txt files, it is working fine. so the question is how to properly open .rtf files as text stream?

Comment: it may be due to rtf file.

Comment: can you try with plain .txt files using notepad ?

Comment: I would open the 3rd file using notepad and check its contents.

Comment: There is no third file.

Comment: @dumb_terminal: Yes, it seems due to rtf files. .txt file gives correct string.

Comment: .rtf files are not intended to be output directly to the console.  They contain formatting information that may be causing you issues.  Find out more about the rtf file format here: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)

Comment: I am not actually intended to be output directly to the console. I am using StreamWriter which also gives the same kind or problem. code example is just to test what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If rtf file is opened, it sometimes saves super hidden(not visible even show hidden file option) temp file as ~filename.rtf which is also read by c#.

I used code from here: [C# - Get a list of files excluding those that are hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418270/c-sharp-get-a-list-of-files-excluding-those-that-are-hidden)

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp");
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles();

var filtered = files.Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden));

foreach (var f in filtered)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(f);
}
```

This solved my problem.